# Http post request after login

Tags: vba, http

My goal is: I want to send a httprequest to get a Post Json after user logged in (user will use Internet Explorer).

So, in my VBA code, I want to allow user to make the login in browser and then he can press a button that will extract the json (in tabular form).

My problem is: How can I attach the InternetExplorer cookies (that already have the credentials) in my http request. I try to send a httprequest however I received "success":false".

If I manually input the URL in Internet Explorer, I can download de json file with success - But my desire is to get this with responseText

My code:

```
Sub GetJson(url as String)

    Dim IE As InternetExplorer
    Dim HTMLdoc As HTMLDocument

    Dim aaa As String

    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

   'Get already open Internet Explorer     
For x = 0 To (objShell.Windows.Count - 1)
        On Error Resume Next
        my_url = objShell.Windows(x).document.Location
        my_title = objShell.Windows(x).document.Title
        If my_title = "MY-PAGE" Then

            Set IE = objShell.Windows(x)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

With IE
        Set HTMLdoc = .document
End With

'Try to Get Json

Dim XMLHTTP As New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60
XMLHTTP.Open "POST", url, False
XMLHTTP.send
xxx = XMLHTTP.responseText
MsgBox xxx

Set objShell = Nothing
Set IE = Nothing
Set HTMLdoc = Nothing

End Sub
```

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Use `MSXML2.XMLHTTP` instead of `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP`

Comment: @omegastripes I tried but without success. the output is the same :(